# JavaScript getElementsByTagName not working correctly

Tags: javascript, dom

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("input").length);
```

is printing out 0. I have found many suggestions online saying that the page is not loaded, but this is not the case. I am running the code via the console on a loaded page (and I have already tried onload). But here is the catch:

The first time I load the page and run it on a computer, the code works correctly and finds all the input elements on the page. However, once I run the code, if I refresh the page, it will always return 0 from there on out. If I switch computers and run the same code, it works fine ONCE and then stops working on refresh.

Furthermore, it's not just limited to "input". It happens to everything (i.e. "a"). Basically I can no longer find ANY elements on the webpage, but they're definitely there. I can inspect the page and look at all of them.

What could be causing this? Is the website blocking JavaScript for me once it sees me using it? If so, what can I do to prevent this from happening?
It's just a simple survey website for my school.

Comment: There is no HTML tag called `<inputs>`.  You *probably* want `document.getElementsByTagName("input")`.

Comment: I meant input. Typed it wrong in here. Situation remains the same.

Comment: @gyre The code is being run from the console on a loaded webpage, so that link does not answer the question. Furthermore, it works fine the first time, it only stops working once the code has been executed once and the page has been refreshed.

Comment: you definitely have to add some more code to your question if you want any help.

Comment: @lexith I mean that is the only code I am trying to run. There is a webpage with tons of input elements. When I run that single line of code in the dev console, it should return the number of input elements on the webpage. It works once, and then stops working. That's it.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the title of the tag is always capitalized, as in all these examples:

https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp

So your code should look something like this:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT").length);
```

Comment: The tag does not need to be capitalized. That being said, capitalizing it does not fix the problem. I want to reiterate that the code works CORRECTLY the first time I run it. Only once I refresh the page does it stop working.

Comment: The argument passed to `getElementsByTagName` is converted to lowercase anyway, according to the spec: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-getelementsbytagname . Don't use w3schools as reference.